# How to insert a line of php code into a text file

Tags: php

I got a problem with my code here. What I'm trying to do is create an index.php file in a user's folder automatically when a user signs up. That has been done actually, now the main problem is how to insert a line of code inside the 'index.php' file created. Below is the line of code I tried using to execute that:

This doesn't work (What I actually want):

```
$filePath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".$_SESSION['username']."/index.php";
$fp = fopen($filePath, 'wb')
or die("can't open file");
$content = "<?php require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/home.php"); ?>";
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);
```

While this does:

```
$filePath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".$_SESSION['username']."/index.php";
$fp = fopen($filePath, 'wb')
or die("can't open file");
$content = "this is a string";
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);
```

So what I want is for the code in the content variable to go into the 'index.php' file. Any help on how to do this?

Comment: What is the error you get? And what is outputted to the index.php file?

Comment: Thanks for your help man! Its been fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed `'` and `"`

Thise line:

```
$content = "<?php require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/home.php"); ?>";
```

should be this:

```
 $content = '<?php require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/home.php"); ?>';
```

Otherwise the interpreter thinkts that at `]."` your string is over and then gets `/home.php` without a connections between it and without it beeing a string. Thus you get an php-error.

Comment: Yours didn't work too

Comment: @Skeellz do you get any error or warning? I changed it a bit. Can you try that aswell??

Comment: Thanks for your help man! Its been fixed

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes in this line:

```
$content = '<?php require($_SERVER[\'DOCUMENT_ROOT\']."/home.php"); ?>';
```

Comment: I've tried your answer still the same error

Comment: What is the error you get? And what is outputted to the index.php file?

Answer (score 0):

Use `\"`

```
"<?php require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].\"/home.php\"); ?>";
```

Comment: I've tried yours too same error

Comment: You're escaping the double quotes unnecessarily. This code will not execute due to syntax errors: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '"/home.php\"); ?>"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING)`

Comment: Yea....thanks man! Just fixed it! The error is as u said....the single n double quotes